# Database and html DOM id mapping

Tags: html, database, dom, mapping, portlet

I am working on a portal, where users can submit and retrieve data from a database via ajax and servlet responses. 
My question is how should i not reveal the real ids of the database in the html DOM. To be more spesific, i need to know which is the best way for mapping between "real" and DOMS's ids, and if this should be happening on server or client side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would like to populate the doms with unique IDs to identify the element in the page. In that case there will be numerous ways.
easy one would be a Fancy value put in the dom like

**dom_id = 'itu~#'+(your_id*1001)+'#rand()'**

Then when requested you can retrieve your_id with the '#'separated and divide by 1001 .

OR

be more complex you may write any complex function

---

Happy coding.